# EF Core 3.1 Unable to mark alternate key optional

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-3.1

> Error: The property 'UserId' on entity type 'Staff' cannot be marked
> as nullable/optional because it has been included in a key {'UserId'}.

I have **Staff** entity, the UserId is nullable

```
public class Staff
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}

builder.Property(e => e.UserId).HasColumnName("user_id").HasMaxLength(32).IsFixedLength(true).IsRequired(false);
```

Another business entity **Manufacturer**, the CreatedBy is required.

```
public class Manufacturer
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual Staff CreatorStaff { get; set; }
}

builder.HasOne(p => p.CreatorStaff).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.CreatedBy).HasPrincipalKey(p => p.UserId);
```

My query:

```
        var result = dbContext.Manufacturers
                            .Where(p => p.TenantId == tenantId)
                            .Where(criteria.Filters)
                            .OrderBy(criteria.OrderBys)
                            .Skip(criteria.Pager.Start)
                            .Take(criteria.Pager.Count)
                            .Select(p => new Manufacturer(p) { Creator = p.CreatorStaff == null ? null : p.CreatorStaff.Name })
                            .AsNoTracking()
                            .ToList();
```

It looks like a bug?

Comment: Hi @Lei Chi, Are you sure your code is correct or are your sure you use ef core3.1? I test your code but it even do not add database successfully with the error: `Column 'Staff.user_id' is not the same data type as referencing column 'Manufacturer.CreatedBy' in foreign key 'FK_Manufacturer_Staff_CreatedBy'`.

Comment: @Rena , this code is the develop code as real and I am using ef core 3.1.4. I wonder if some database can't create unique constaint on nullable columns, so this could be restriction in ef core(As I am using postgresql and works fine).  Or should I update ef core to 3.1.16(lastest)?

Comment: This is partial code and database first way, as your error, make sure the StaffConfiguration property UserId and ManufacturerConfiguration CreatedBy have the same datatype(char(32)), I can add Staff/Manufacturer as wish.

Comment: I've also file a bug on github, hope they can show me the mistake. 
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/25107

Comment: in your staff entity, there is something like ```IsRequired(false);````and u cant do that to the because its a string. U cant create nullable string objects. if the string empty, its gonna look like that User_ID="";

Comment: Issue comfirmed

> Since UserId is target of a relationship, EF Core makes it alternate key. Key properties in EF Core cannot be marked as required. Probably there is a tracking issue to relax this constraint.
So i am going to use "left join" with linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate Key not allowed to be nullable, It is disscussed very early, and issue still opened after 5 years. Owners insist that making alternate key optional is not reasonable
You may want a look at [this](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/4415) for detail

Use "Left join" syntax instead, for me now.